# How to fix this invalid regular expression flag w below?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to receive a name of a file from a php script which is in one page and append it in a javascript function which is on a seperate page. The problem is that I am getting an invalid regular expression flag w error in my error console which states undefine variable: 'fileimagename for the line below:

```
 var nameimagefile = <?php echo $fileimagename; ?>;
```

How can I fix this error?

Below is javascript function (QandATable.php):

```
function stopImageUpload(success){

     var nameimagefile = <?php echo $fileimagename; ?>;
      var result = '';
      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';
         $('.listImage').append(nameimagefile + '<br/>');
      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
      }

return true;

}
```

Below is the php code which is on a seperate page (imageupload.php) where the file name is:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['fileimagename'])) {

$_SESSION['fileimagename'] =  $_SESSION[' $_FILES['fileImage']['name']'];

}

if( file_exists("ImageFiles/".$_FILES['fileImage']['name'])) {
    $parts = explode(".",$_FILES['fileImage']['name']);
    $ext = array_pop($parts);
    $base = implode(".",$parts);
    $n = 2;

    while( file_exists("ImageFiles/".$base."_".$n.".".$ext)) $n++;
    $_FILES['fileImage']['name'] = $base."_".$n.".".$ext;

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
    "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
    $result = 1;

}
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
      "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
      $result = 1;

      }

?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.window.stopImageUpload(<?php echo $result;?>);</script>
```

Comment: I don't see a regular expression.

Comment: what does it mean no regular expression?

Comment: What does _what_ mean, "no regular expression?" What is the JavaScript code that the **browser** sees?

Comment: The browser doesn't show anything, because there is an error it is not showing anything on the page.

Comment: I'm not talking about what the browser shows the user. Do you know how to use your browser's developer tools?

Comment: It states in error console invalid regular expression flag w error in my error console which states undefine variable: 'fileimagename for the line below:

Comment: The assignment also won't work as bare word. If it's supposed to be a string, it needs quotes; better yet json_encode().

Comment: so what is the line of code with the json.endcode()?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is saying `$fileimagename` is not set.

```
var nameimagefile = <?php echo $fileimagename; ?>;
```

You need to define `$fileimagename`

Comment: I have tried: `$fileimagename = $_SESSION['fileimagename'];` above javascript code in php but it says fileimagename is undefined

Comment: try `var_dump($_SESSION['fileimagename'])` and see what it contains

Comment: After the var dump it is stating NULL. Is it not retireving the file name? Im my code in the question above is the code correct or are they in wrong places? Also where does `$fileimagename = $_SESSION['fileimagename'];` I am not sure if they are in right places so I don't think it is retrieving  file names? When user accesses javascript function, that means the file has been uploaded so it should retireve it's name`

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in `QandATable.php`, you should have a `$fileimagename = $_SESSION['fileimagename']`, or something that sets that var.

Comment: I have tried: `$fileimagename = $_SESSION['fileimagename'];` above javascript code in php but it says fileimagename is undefined

Comment: You need to do it in the PHP file that has the javascript, and before the javascript.